# Cannot save dataframe to parquet pyspark

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I'm having some issues regarding saving the dataframe into parquet. It prompts an error as below.
This is the code that i want to convert to parquet file
`test3.write.parquet('/spark/bin/test4.parquet')`

This is the error that I got:

> ```
>     Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 936, in parquet
>     self._jwrite.parquet(path)
>   File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line
>  1305, in __call__
>   File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 134, in deco
>     raise_from(converted)
>   File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: path file:/spark/bin/test4.parquet already exists.;
> >>> test3.write.parquet('/spark/bin/test5.parquet')
> 21/04/29 11:09:07 ERROR Utils: Aborting task=========>              (6 + 2) / 8]
> java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> 21/04/29 11:09:07 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Job job_20210429110901_0045 aborted.
> 21/04/29 11:09:07 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 45.0 (TID 328)
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
>         ... 9 more
> 21/04/29 11:09:07 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 7 in stage 45.0 failed 1 times; aborting job
> 21/04/29 11:09:07 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job 2a8c5e91-0b62-49af-acf7-1cda1b381429.
> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 7 in stage 45.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
> 7.0 in stage 45.0 (TID 328, Mimos.realtek, executor driver): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
>         ... 9 more
>
> Driver stacktrace:
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:2059)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2(DAGScheduler.scala:2008)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$abortStage$2$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:62)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray.foreach$(ResizableArray.scala:55)
>         at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:49)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:2007)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1$adapted(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
>         at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:407)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:973)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2239)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2188)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:2177)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:49)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:775)
>         at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2099)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:195)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:131)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$execute$1(SparkPlan.scala:175)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$executeQuery$1(SparkPlan.scala:213)
>         at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:210)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:171)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:122)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:121)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.$anonfun$runCommand$1(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$5(SQLExecution.scala:100)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:160)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:87)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:764)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:963)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:415)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:399)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:288)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.parquet(DataFrameWriter.scala:848)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>         at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
>         at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
>         at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
>         at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
>         at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
>         at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Task failed while writing rows.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:291)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:205)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
>         at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:127)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:446)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1377)
>         at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:449)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>         ... 1 more
> Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Ljava/lang/String;I)Z
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access0(Native Method)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$Windows.access(NativeIO.java:645)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.canRead(FileUtil.java:1230)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileUtil.list(FileUtil.java:1435)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.listStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:493)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1868)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.listStatus(FileSystem.java:1910)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.listStatus(ChecksumFileSystem.java:678)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.mergePaths(FileOutputCommitter.java:484)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:597)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.commitTask(FileOutputCommitter.java:560)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.performCommit$1(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:50)
>         at org.apache.spark.mapred.SparkHadoopMapRedUtil$.commitTask(SparkHadoopMapRedUtil.scala:77)
>         at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.commitTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:245)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatDataWriter.commit(FileFormatDataWriter.scala:79)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$executeTask$1(FileFormatWriter.scala:275)
>         at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinallyAndFailureCallbacks(Utils.scala:1411)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:281)
>         ... 9 more
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
>   File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 936, in parquet
>     self._jwrite.parquet(path)
>   File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line
>  1305, in __call__
>   File "C:\spark\python\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 128, in deco
>     return f(*a, **kw)
>   File "C:\spark\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
> py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o178.parquet.
> : org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted.
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:178)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:108)
>         at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:106)
>         at
> ```

Comment: can you share a sample of your data, how you loaded it and transformation etc?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the logs the error is pretty clear:

> pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: path file:/spark/bin/test4.parquet already exists.;

You can modify your code to overwrite if it already exists like this:

```
test3.write.parquet('/spark/bin/test4.parquet', mode="overwrite")
```

Comment: That's not true, from the stack trace it showing error due to this command `>>> test3.write.parquet('/spark/bin/test5.parquet')`, so `test5.parquet` is new that is not the problem